# Build flavors for different version of same class with small changes

Tags: android, gradle, build, version, configure

I have an android app with a java class for configure.I want to make two product flavors with different version of same class with small changes.

```
 flavorDimensions "flavor"
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "flavor"
            applicationId "net.flavor1"
        }

        flavor2{
            dimension "flavor"
            applicationId "net.flavor2"
        }


    }

    sourceSets {
        flavor1 {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/net.flavor1/Configuration.java']

        }

        flavor2{
            java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/Configuration.java']


        }
    }
```

Comment: If there is a small change you can also check using a boolean or packageName check

Answer (score 0):

Just add the different versions of your class in `src/flavor1` and `src/flavor2` (in same package structure).  You don't need to add those `java.srcDirs` settings. For example, if your `Configuration` class is in `com.example` package then you'd have

```
src/flavor1/com/example/Configuration.java
src/flavor2/com/example/Configuration.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `versionName` and `versionCode` under each flavor. If you leave it empty. Gradle would use the default one

```
flavorDimensions "flavor"
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "flavor"
            applicationId "net.flavor1"
            versionName "2.0.1"
            versionCode 31
        }

        flavor2{
            dimension "flavor"
            applicationId "net.flavor2"
            versionName "1.0.1"
            versionCode 3
        }


    }

    sourceSets {
        flavor1 {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/net.flavor1/Configuration.java']

        }

        flavor2{
            java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/Configuration.java']


        }
    }
```